# How to send message from input text to HTTP?

Tags: javascript, html, http

So in android phone application called DroidScript is example of HTTP server where when click button it sends message,in phone it receives and shows as popup.
I want to send message that is typed in input text but the problem is:
I don't know how and i'm newbie.
Here is code:

HTML code

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Web Server Demo</title>

 <script>
function SendMessage( msg )
{
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { HandleReply(httpRequest); };  
    httpRequest.open("GET", "/message?msg=" + msg, true);
    httpRequest.send(null);
}

function HandleReply( httpRequest )
{
    if( httpRequest.readyState==4 ) 
    {
        if( httpRequest.status==200 ) txt.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
        else txt.innerHTML = "Error: " + httpRequest.status + " " +  httpRequest.responseText;
    }
}
  </script>
  </head>


  <body>
 <h1>Web Server Demo</h1> 
 <img src="Hello World/Img/Hello World.png" width="72"> 
 
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br><br>
     <b>File upload:</b> <br>
    Image<input type="file" name="Img" /> <br>
    Sound<input type="file" name="Snd" /> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <br>
</form>

   <br>
   <a href="Hello World/">Directory Listing</a>
   <br><br><br>
   <button onclick="SendMessage('hello')">send</button>
   <font id="txt" size="5"></font>

   </body>
   </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT in phone app Droidscript

```
     //Called when application is started.
 function OnStart()
         {
                //Check wifi is enabled.
           var ip = app.GetIPAddress()
     if( ip == "0.0.0.0" ) { 
         alert( "Please Enable Wi-Fi" ) 
    app.Exit()
}
//Create a layout with objects vertically centered.
lay = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "VCenter,FillXY" )    

//Create a text label and add it to layout.
var s = "Type the following address into your" + 
        " browser\n\n" + ip +":8080";
txt = app.CreateText( s, 0.8, 0.5, "MultiLine" )
txt.SetTextSize( 22 )
lay.AddChild( txt )

//Add layout to app.    
app.AddLayout( lay )

//Create and run web server.
serv = app.CreateWebServer( 8080, "Upload,ListDir" )
serv.SetFolder( "/sdcard/DroidScript" )
serv.AddServlet( "/message", OnServlet )
serv.Start()
 }

       //Handle servlet requests.
      function OnServlet( request, info )
      {
serv.SetResponse( "Got it!" )
app.ShowPopup(  info.remoteAddress + " says: " + request.msg )
}
```